# Getting docker daemon not running error

Tags: docker

I am trying to get docker working on my sys
However, not able to

Steps to reproduce the issue that I am facing:

1. Installed EPEL on 6.5 RHEL
2. Installed docker-io
3. Able to run "docker" command
4. When running "docker run -i -t fedora /bin/bash" command using without root, getting below error:

   FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create: 
   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock 
     http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create:%20dial%20unix%20/var/run/docker.sock : 
     permission denied. 
     Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

However, with root getting diff error like below for the same command:

```
FATA[0000] Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

Comment: @Ramesh This mean the client can't connect to the engine. First, you have to check if the daemon is running or not. You have several ways to do that but a ``ps aux | grep docker`` should help you see if it's running. If it's running then it's either a permission problem (try ``sudo docker ps``) or a connection problem (try ``export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375`` or ``docker -h 127.0.0.1:2375 ps``).

Answer (score 1):

A [RHEL 6.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux#RHEL_6), also termed Update 5, is from 21 November 2013 and [comes with kernel 2.6.32-431](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL6).

That seems quite an old kernel for docker to be installed and run successfully. Docker would need ideally a 3.10+ kernel.
Although [Adrian Mouat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332/adrian-mouat) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166055/getting-docker-daemon-not-running-error/30166187#comment48444922_30166187) that the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 (64-bit) or later](https://docs.docker.com/installation/rhel/#red-hat-enterprise-linux-6.5-installation) is supported

> You will need 64 bit RHEL 6.5 or later, with a RHEL 6 kernel version 2.6.32-431 or higher as this has specific kernel fixes to allow Docker to work.

So make sure the docker daemon is started:

```
sudo service docker start
```

Then try some sudo docker commands:

```
sudo docker run -i -t fedora /bin/bash
```

The doc mentions:

> If you get a `Cannot start container` error mentioning `SELinux` or `permission denied`, you may need to update the SELinux policies.
>   This can be done using **`sudo yum upgrade selinux-policy`** and then rebooting.

Comment: From the docs: "RHEL 6 kernel version 2.6.32-431 or higher ... has specific kernel fixes to allow Docker to work."

Comment: @AdrianMouat Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly and added some other checks to do.